# Estimator of true probability -- understanding margin of error for very small probability

Tags: probability, estimation, error

I have a coin whose probability of landing on heads when flipped is unknown, but could be anywhere between 0 and 100%.  I want to flip the coin some number of times and estimate the true probability of the coin landing on heads.  I've been looking at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair), which gives several seemingly useful formulas and examples, including the following:

> If a maximum error of 0.01 is desired, how many times should the coin
>   be tossed?
>
> n = 2500,  at 68.27% level of confidence (Z=1)
>
> n = 10000,  at 95.45% level of confidence (Z=2)

However, after thinking about some specific cases, I have some confusion.  What exactly is meant by "a maximum error of 0.01"?  If I flip the coin 10,000 times and it comes up heads 200 times, does a .01 margin of error represent 100 "heads" results (0.01 of all flips -- 95% confidence the true probability is in the range [0.01,0.03]) or 2 "heads" results (0.01 of all "heads" results -- 95% confidence the true probability is in the range [0.0198,0.0202])?  I had assumed it was the former, but then I considered this:

Suppose I flip the coin 100 times, and it comes up tails 100 times.  The equation from the article shows that the margin of error for 95% confidence (Z=2) is 0.1.  This seems to mean that the actual probability of "heads" might be as high as 10% (and even higher 5% of the time).  But what are the chances that a coin with 10% probability of "heads" lands on tails 100 times in a row?  .9^100 = 0.000026.  Even if the true probability is only .05, my result would only be reached 0.5% of the time.  It seems like my actual margin of error for 95% confidence is around .03, since .97^100 = .048.

So... what gives?  Are the formulas in the article only useful when the probability is near .5?  How can I adjust them to work when the probability is near 0?

Also, can I improve my estimates (or be more confident of them) if I know the allowable range for the true probability?  (e.g. in the range [.4,.9] or [0,.05])

Comment: The issue is the line $\displaystyle s_p = \sqrt{ \frac {p \, (1-p) } {n} } \le \sqrt{ \frac {0.5 \times 0.5 } {n} } = \frac {1}{2 \, \sqrt{n}}$ related to the title of the article *Checking whether a coin is fair*. If instead $p$ is close to $0$ or $1$, then $s_p$ will be much smaller.  You might want to read the Wikipedia article [*Binomial proportion confidence interval*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) which has some other approaches

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  In the article you linked, it seems like the Wilson interval might work for me.  Could you explain how to calculate the value of the p-hat symbol?  (is it just (h/h+t)?)

Comment: It looks like it.  Note that $\tilde{p}$ is slightly different to $\hat{p}$